# Embedded FOP: How to change PDF version programmatically?

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop

I'm using embedded FOP 2.2 in our Java application. It works fine and generates PDF 1.4. I want to upgrade to PDF 1.5, 1.6. or 1.7. I know that I can do it in the configuration file (1.5) but due to my circumstances I cannot use a config file. I configure FOP in my Java code. Here is my code:

```
FopFactoryBuilder builder = new FopFactoryBuilder(new URI("http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format")); 

builder.setStrictFOValidation(true); 

builder.setBreakIndentInheritanceOnReferenceAreaBoundary(false); 

builder.setSourceResolution(72); 

builder.setTargetResolution(72); 

FopFactory fopFactory = builder.build(); 

FOUserAgent userAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

userAgent.getRendererOptions().put("version", "1.7"); 

Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, userAgent, outputStream); 

Result result = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
```

As you can see I set the version to 1.7 in the FOPUserAgent and I pass the fopuseragent to the newFop() method. I expect a PDF in version 1.7, but the generated PDF is in version 1.4 :-(

I don't know exactly if the line

**userAgent.getRendererOptions().put("version", "1.7");**

is correct, maybe the key "version" is wrong. I couldn't find a list on the Apache FOP site with all the keys.

Does anyone know the correct syntax for changing the pdf version in Java? As I mentioned I cannot use a configuration file. It must be done in Java.

Thanks friends

Michael